# How can I delete the previous history state after the page is loaded using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to delete the previous history state, after the page is loaded.

This is a separate question from my other question; not merely an alternative.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190808/how-to-clear-browsers-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-history-using-javascript-or-j

Answer (score 7):

If you're loading new page via JS, you can `replace` its location to use the same history entry:

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969975/141343) answer.

Another way is to use [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).