# URL handling on browser BACK button

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am making a simple web app that opens a url on entering a query. I am using the bottle framework in Python. The problem I am facing is as follows:

I have two URL handlers, one for `/` and other for `/process`. When the user enters a query through a form on `/`, the form action goes to `/process` which then processes the query and opens a particular url using `window.open(url, "_self")`. Now when the user hits the back button in the browser, `/process` is called again with the same query, which then again loads the same url. Instead of this, I want it to go `/` when the back button is pressed. How can I do this? Thanks.

EDIT : I did not notice this before but the above undesired behavior is found in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window.history object to manipulate and replace the history or, instead of using `window.open(url, "_self")`, replace the location

example:

```
window.location.replace(url);
```

Check [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and this answer
[In Javascript, how do I "clear" the back (history -1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969878/in-javascript-how-do-i-clear-the-back-history-1/8969959#8969959)

Another solution could be to intercept when the user is going to go back. Check this answer to have some examples:

[Intercepting call to the back button in my AJAX application: I don't want it to do anything!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to)

Comment: The solution worked. Please see my question edit. Any clue why the problem was browser dependent?

Comment: how was the url passed to `window.open` formed?

Comment: It wasn't actually formed. It was selected out from a list of urls returned by a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't redirect using `window.open`, or any kind of client-side JavaScript.

Have the HTTP response to the request for `/process` be a `302 Found` HTTP status with a `Location` header.

See also [The Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: +1 for the elaborative wikipedia link. Any reason why the problem was browser dependent?