# Remove page from history, so "back" will work properly

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, back

I have my app that you need to login to get in to the other pages.

so the first page is "login" and it checks if you are already logged, if so you will be redirected to the main page app, if not it will show you the login page.

now the problem is when the user is inside the logged page area, and he clicks back he will get to the "login" page and than redirected back to the main page, as he is logged in already.

So he is stuck in an infinite loop.

how can I remove the login page from the history.

just like in android "android remove activity from history stack"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

here is the solution!

simply use:

```
  $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
     disableBack: true
  });
```

example for login function:

```
$scope.login = function () {

Security.login($scope.cred.email, $scope.cred.password)
    .success(function(data) {
        Security.setUser(data.data[0]);
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
            disableBack: true
        });
        $state.go('posts', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});
    }).error(function(data) {
        $scope.showAlert();
    });
};
```

Comment: $ionicViewService has now been deprecated, but you can use [$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/service/$ionicHistory/#nextViewOptions) instead.

Comment: And you should use historyRoot: true in place of disableBack: true in that case :)

Answer (score 25):

For a pure AngularJS way to accomplish this (rather than ionic or javascript in the other answers), use the $location service's replace() method ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)) :

Use `$location.url('/newpath');` or `$location.path('/newpath');` as you normally would to do the redirection in angular. And then just add `$location.replace();` right after it. Or you can chain the commands like this:

```
$location.url('/newpath').replace();
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969975/185672

**Top answer:**

Instead of using `window.location = url;` to redirect,

try `window.location.replace(url);`.

> after using replace() the current page will not be saved in session
>   history, meaning the user won't be able to use the Back button to
>   navigate to it.

Comment: I used the ui-router command:  $state.go('posts', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});   and it stills pops on back button