# Angularjs browser back button

Tags: angularjs

Hie , I am using angularjs for building an end to end application.My functionality are following :

Default page is Login 
After login get successful user is redirected to home page where he can search filter and can save his search.

I m facing problem with following use case: When user search some result and after that if he save some search history.If he press the browser back button the page must be redirect to again search result but page is redirected to login page always.

I want whenever user press back button of browser the page should be redirected to previous page not to login.
The complete home page is single page html and the functionality are managed by ng-if.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441698/remove-page-from-history-so-back-will-work-properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441698/remove-page-from-history-so-back-will-work-properly)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use guards in application check weather user is logged in or not.

```
@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

auth: any = {};

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {

}

canActivate() {
    if (/*user is logged in*/) {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```