# Javascript: How to navigate back and remove current state from history?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets imagine we have to html sites:

```
- login
- register
```

I start at `login` and i navigate to `register`, so my history stack is now:

```
login -> register
```

What i now need is a JavaScript function to navigate back from `register` to `login`

```
login <- register
```

and delete the register history entry so that the user cant use forward to get back to the `register` site.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the register page you could...

```
location.replace("/login");
```

... this should not add an item to the history - see: [In Javascript, how do I "clear" the back (history -1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969878/in-javascript-how-do-i-clear-the-back-history-1).

Comment: Yes indeed. it does not add an item to the history. but i now have two times `login` in the history `login -> login`.

Comment: Could use it to navigate to the register page too then..?

Comment: @BillyMoon Sure, but then the user cannot use the back button to get back to the login page from register.